# Can't start another Activity if AsyncTask is already running in backgroud Service

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I just noticed that when my `Service` does tasks running `AsyncTask` on the background, and I try to launch new `Activity` which also uses its own `AsyncTask`, then `Activity` about to launch freezes until `Services` `AsyncTask` has completed and then launches, running its own `AsyncTask`. This problem doesn't occur if the `Activity` that is about to launch doesn't have any `AsyncTask` tasks. Do I have to somehow allow two seperate AsyncTask to run at the same time or is there something else I should know?

Comment: `AsyncTask` tasks can coexist nicely. It's probably something in your code. Are you launching the second activity from the first `AsyncTask`?

Comment: I am launching all Activities from main Activity by clicking on button.

Comment: may be you are using `AsyncTask.get()` method for getting result back from AsyncTask?

Comment: In Services AsyncTask I dont use it, but in other activities I do use get(). But without Services AsyncTask running on the background there are no problems even if I use get()

Comment: @RohitMalish : and when you are starting AsyncTask in Activity? ok fine  can you try it just after commenting `AsyncTask.get()` in Activity? and see result's it's hanging or not

Comment: Other activities run asynctask on create. I tried commenting out whole asynctask in other activities and now they dont freeze that way.

Comment: Post some code to help us understand the issue.